# Dummy variables are removed when estimating first-differences

Tags: econometrics, first-difference

I am currently getting ready for Econometrics 1 exam and I have some problems deriving the FD estimator sometimes.

Lets say we have a data set with the following observations:

$FoodAS_{it}$ = food assumption pr day for person i in year t,

$Weight_{it}$ = weight for person i in year t

and a dummy variable: $Bicity_{it}$ = a dummy for big cities

We have the following model

$Weight_{it} = \beta_1FoodAS_{it} + \beta_2 Bigcity_{it}, t = \{2010,2015\} $

When calculating the estimator, I would say we get

$$
\Delta Weight_{it} = Weight_{i2} - Weight_{i1} = \beta_1(FoodAS_{i2} - FoodAS_{i2}) + \beta_2(Bigcity_{i2} - Bigcity_{i1})
$$
But for some reason, the result states that the correct answer is
$$
\Delta Weight_{it} = Weight_{i2} - Weight_{i1} = \beta_1(FoodAS_{i2} - FoodAS_{i2})
$$
I have noticed this multiple times. Almost always, the dummy variables are removed. Why is this?

Kind regards

Comment: First-differencing in the within/time-series dimension is going to remove any variable that is time-invariant---e.g. fixed effect. Here, there may be an implicit assumption that the "Bigcity" dummy is time-invariant. Someone in the dataset either lives or not lives in a big city for both periods.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much